# String mismatch by single letter

Tags: java, string

I want to find out wheather a string has single mismatch.

```
1)CHARACTER INTERCHANGE W/O DISTURBING PATTERN
ACRPG0182F v/s ACRPG0812F
ACNPA4428K v/s ACHPA4428K

2)CHARACTER LENGTH DIFFERS BY 1 DIGIT
ACRPG0182F v/s ACRPG0812
ACRPG0182F v/s CRPG0812F
```

In case 1 both string length is same but it has 1 character mismatch
In case 2 both string length differ by 1 and any one character can be mismatched in both String.

Comment: any information on expected length of those strings?

Comment: in case 1 length of both string is same and in case 2 the string differ by 1 letter

Comment: I mean if you don't want algorithm that will work fast enough on 30000 char Strings, you can go with straight and simple solutions (iter all the way all Strings).

Comment: Just to clarify - in the 2nd case the strings are 1 character different in length, and have the same characters in (except the one missing one). Is that what you want to catch; same characters and a length one shorter?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 4):

- get the number using regex (`\d+`)
- fill a `Set` with all characters (`numberStr.toCharArray()`)
- use [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `Sets` - `Sets.difference(set1, set2)` and see if it has exactly one element

Originally I thought you need to check the difference in a different way: whether only one digit is different, rather than "the string contains only one different digit, regardless of the order". If order is also important, just calculate the [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and see if it's equal to 1.

`StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(s1, s2)` from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) will do it.

Comment: If you apply the examples from the question on this [link](http://www.merriampark.com/ld.htm) you get a distance of 2. Not sure it will be enough for the need.

Comment: you even get 3. That's why I added the Sets.difference solution

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Bozho, using the [levenstein distance](http://www.merriampark.com/ld.htm) is probably the most direct route to solving your problem. The definition from that page appears to be exactly what you're asking for.

> Levenshtein distance (LD) is a measure of the similarity between two
>   strings, which we will refer to as the source string (s) and the
>   target string (t). The distance is the number of deletions,
>   insertions, or substitutions required to transform s into t.

Comment: as I look more into his examples, this won't work. He needs a different logic

Comment: From the way I'm reading his question, yes and no. It seems like he needs a levenstein distance of 1 OR a distance of 2 where the two items in question are effectively swapping letters with each other. Depending on the input, using the levenstein algorithm to filter down the inputs to only those with 1-2 distance, then analyzing the 2s to check for the additional constraint seems like a reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Define an Xor function on strings.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of `1`, take a look at the algorithm in the link.

Comment: as I look more into his examples, this won't work. He needs a different logic